# dynamically move arc (canvas)

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Working on arc (Canvas html) i have created arc using Canvas now i want to move the arc from 0 - 100 % i have created variable name call linevalue= "0"   if i enter the line value as 40% it has to move accordingly again if i enter value as 20% it has to come down.

I have added linevalue in myCurve().

But still I am not getting the result

Can anyone suggest me on this

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');  
function myCurve(x,y,linevalue){  
 context.translate(x,y);
 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(0,0,linevalue);
 context.quadraticCurveTo(85,18,120,0);
 context.lineWidth = 2;
 context.strokeStyle = 'Orange';
 context.stroke();
 context.translate(-x,-y);
}
```

Here is my entire code in fiddle

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wkAsA/)

Thanks in advance
Mahadevan

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your project relies heavily on some simple trigonometry. So it's time to brush up on your trigonometry.

The depth of the quadratic curve is determined by its `control point`.

Here’s how to calculatate the control point mathematically:

- Start with an imaginary line between the starting and ending points of your quadratic curve (call it lineSE).
- Calc the angle of lineSE using Math.atan2.
- Calc the midpoint of lineSE using linear interpolation.
- Your quad-curve control point is along a line tangent to lineSE at the midpoint.  The tangent angle is lineSE angle + Math.PI/2.
- The closer the control point is to lineSE the shallower the quadratic curve becomes.  At 0% the curve is flat – it becomes lineSE.
- Your design determines how big the arc must be at 100%, but your control point will always set the size of the arc at any percentage you determine.

Comment: hi @markE can you help me on this i am struggling lot and I am not  getting the result

Comment: It appears you are struggling because you need to study the math that makes your project work.  Check out quick online tutorials on trigonometry and geometry. When you have that understanding my answer above should help.  Good luck with your learning and your project!

Comment: hi markE I have tried reading trigonometry but truly speaking till now i am not getting anything could you please help me in this

Comment: Here is my answer put to work in code.  But quite frankly, if you haven't learned some basic trigonometry & geometry then it might not be relevant to you:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ExcC8/

Comment: hi markE thank you so much i will try and apply the code in my project to move up and down the curve line